# How to make general_log(mysql) file into daily copy?

Tags: mysql

Need help on this.

I would like to make my general_log file for mysql from single huge file into a daily log file.

I created a batch file to rename and create anew general log file,
but it still write into the renamed file.

Are there a config in mysql or am I missing a command here, so that the general log will not write on the renamed file / or just create a new general log / or will just write to the new empty file? thanks in advance

btw, batch file is below:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set 
dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

ren C:\wamp\logs\generalmysql.log "generalmysql - %stamp%.log"

@echo off
 echo.>"C:\wamp\logs\generalmysql.log"
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSTqk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved my issue by flushing the logs

```
call "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin\mysqladmin.exe" -u'root' -h localhost flush-logs
```